# Salesforce CPQ: JS Calc working and returning values in backend but values are not reflecting real time

Tags: cpq, js, customization, cpq-plugins

I am using the JS QCP Plugin to update the QLI level field value then that value is referenced in a price rule of event On Calculate

I tried wrapping up the query in a new promise return but still, it's not waiting for the execution to complete.

```
// onBeforePriceRules 
export function onBeforePriceRules(quote, lines, conn) {
log('onBeforePriceRules');   
calculateSlabDiscountUnitPrice(lines, conn);
return Promise.resolve();
}

function calculateSlabDiscountUnitPrice(lines, conn){

    lines
    .forEach(line =>{
            var querystring = 'SELECT Id .....;
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            conn.query(querystring)
            .then(function(results) {
                //here processing the result and updating Quote Line fields

                resolve(lines);
                });
            });
        });
  }
```

I referred answer mentioned here by @Pawel Fronczak but still no luck -
[Salesforce CPQ - JS Calc Works But Does Not Show In UI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220296/salesforce-cpq-js-calc-works-but-does-not-show-in-ui)

Any help would be much appreciated!